# Most effective way to create a naive text summaring algorithm

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, parsing, summarization

I'm building a simple naive text summary algorithm. The algorithm works like this:

- First step of my algorithm is to remove all stop words([stop words in English](http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords)).
- After my text contains only words with actual meaning I'm going to see how many times each word is used in the text to find the frequency of the word. For example if the word "supercomputer" is used 5 times, it will have `frequency = 5`.
- Then I'm going to calculate each sentences weight by dividing the `sum of the frequencies of all words in the sentence` to the `number of the words in the sentence`.
- On the last step I'm going to sort the sentences by their length.

I need to write this algorithm in C++ (as V8 NodeJS module), but the problem is that in the past few years I've been working mostly with high-level scripting languages like Javascript and I'm not that experienced in C++. In javascript I could just use regex to remove all stop words and then find the frequency, but in C++ seems to be much more complex.

I came up with the following idea:

```
struct words {
    string word;
    int freq;
}

std::vector<words> Words;
```

- The stop words are going to be preloaded in a V8 Local Array or std::vector.
- For each word in the text I'm going to loop through all stop words, if the current word is not a stop word, then check if its in the struct, if not -> add a new `word` to the `Words vector`, if exists increase freq by 1.
- After I have found all the frequencies of all words, I'm going to loop through the text again to find the weight of each sentence.

And with this idea few problems came to my mind:

1. My texts will be mostly 1000+ words. And for each word looping through 100+ stop words are going to make 100000 iterations just to figure out the stop words. This seems to be really ineffective.
2. After I have the frequencies I will need to loop one more time through the text 1000+ words with 300+ words(in the vector frequencies) to calculate each sentences weight.

My idea seems to be ineffective, but I'm not well familiar with C++.

**So my questions is are there better ways to do this or optimize my algorithm, especially the problems I listed above?**

I'm worried about the performance of my algorithm and any tips/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right of the bat you could setup an `unordered_map` to hold the stop words instead of a `std::vector` so checking if a word is a stop word is `O(1)` as opposed to looping through the 100+ stop words, as you stated.

Comment: You can also store the found words in a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) which is O(log n) most of the time.

Comment: Or use an `unordered_map` for both. Every time you find a word, update its frequency. This will take `O(n)` time. Computing the weight of the sentences will then just be a matter of looking up the frequencies of the words, which is `O(1)` with `unordered_map`, and `O(n)` with a `vector`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I really appreciate them. I just would like to also ask what will be the best way to split the words? The thing that come on my mind is `while ((pos = input.find(' ', pos)) != std::string::npos) {` while I keep the pos of last match and then `str.substr` them. Is that effective?

Comment: This really is off-topic. It's too broad. There are many ways to solve the problem. There isn't much attempted code.

Comment: @RSahu, that  is a good point but I don't think it is too broad, OP is just asking for tips to optimize his retrievals and scans

Comment: For splitting, all of the input stream classes use whitespace as the delimiter already. So you could do it at reading time (inFile >> word), or later by loading it into an istringstream and then using the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For the stopwords, have a look at [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). You can store all of your stopword strings in a `std::unordered_set<string>`, then when you have a string you want to compare, call `count(string)` to see if it exists.

For the word/frequency pairs, use a `std::unordered_map` as in some of the comments. It would be fastest if you perform both the find and insert in a single map lookup. Try something like this:

```
struct Frequency
{
    int val;
    Frequency() : val(0) {}
    void increment()
    {
        ++val;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Frequency> words;

void processWord(const std::string str)
{
    words[str].increment();
}
```

`words[str]` searches for a word in the map, adding it if it doesn't exist. New words will call Frequency's constructor which initializes to zero. So all you have to do is call `processWord` on every word.